# Rolling a fair die 18 times, what is the probability of rolling 1,2,3,4,5,6 (each) three times?

Tags: probability, multinomial-coefficients

The problem statement and solution is below. I understand that each die toss is independent but it doesn't make sense to me why the probability is multiplied by the number of sequences, as in the solution.

When you roll a die 18 times, it is possible to get a countable number of sequences such that a 1,2,3,4,5,6 each appear 3 times. Wouldn't the probability that each number appears exactly 3 times be equal to the ratio of the number of sequences in which 1,2,3,4,5,6 appear 3 times to the total number of sequences you can have (6^18)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This questions ask you for the number of possible sequences that meet your conditions.

So, consider this: The sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6 is not the same sequence as 1,3,2,6,5,4. However, each number has occurred exactly once. Since order matters, you must treat this as a permutation.

You could roll something like: {(1,2,3,4,5,6)  (1,2,3,4,5,6) (1,2,3,4,5,6)} or something like {(1,1,1,2,2,2) (3,3,3,4,4,4) ...} and as you can see both meet your criteria and both are different.

So, $$(\frac{1}{6})^{18}$$

is the probability of one of these possible sequences occurring.

$$\frac{18!}{(3!)^6}$$

gives the possible number of these sequences.

$$(\frac{1}{6})^{18}\frac{18!}{(3!)^6}$$

yields the probability of any such sequence occurring.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialCoefficient.html is a good link for multinomial coefficient, which John correctly mentions in his answer.

Comment: The last statement would be how I would represent the solution algebraically. I'm unsure if it doesn't make sense to say that the solution is the probability of one of these events that fits our condition occurring times the number of sequences that fits our condition.

Comment: Is that equivalent to saying that it's the _ratio_ of "what we want" to the total number of ways it can happen (the total number of possible sequences we can have, rolling a die 18 times).

Comment: Yes, I think could find this using the $\frac{N_a}{N}$ method if you prefer. Where $N_a$ are all the different ways we could roll a die 18 times and meet our given conditions and N represents every possible outcome for rolling a die 18 times.

Answer (score 0):

> Wouldn't the probability that each number appears exactly 3 times be equal to the ratio of the number of sequences in which 1,2,3,4,5,6 appear 3 times to the total number of sequences you can have (6^18)?

Yes, and the number of sequences is exactly what's calculated with the multinomial coefficient.  You choose the positions in the sequence for the $1$'s, then for the $2$'s, and so forth.  The collection of these sequences is counted by the multinomial coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6 (assuming that OP meant this) is just one of the possible permutations of 18 die rolls. There are $6^{18}$ such permutations in total. Therefore the odds are 1 in $6^{18}$, or $(6^{18}) - 1$ to 1 against.

Comment: I doubt this is what the OP meant.  You are counting the number of all possible sequences that result from rolling a die six times including $1,2,6,3, 6,2, 5, 1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 2 ,6, 6, 1,2, 5$, but this string/sequence cannot be included, like many many sequences cannot be included in the number of *those for which each digit on the die appears exactly three times.*

Comment: Aah, I see now, yes - forgive me for being slow and thanks for your comment!